# How to make certain user data available without logging in using devise gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am a beginner to rails and have decided to make a simple CRUD application as a personal project.

I have used the devise gem for authentication and can-can for authorization.

In short, the user is a student who logs in and enters his personal details,marks and the application calculates his percentage.

the 'marks' page displays data such as:

name: xyz

subject1:45

subject2:67

subject3:91

I want the 'marks' page to be visible to anybody on the internet by simply typing in the correct http address which will of course include the user id(i.e without logging in to rails under the user model). However the 'student details' page should require authentication to view.

How am I supposed to approach this problem ? Using gems in rails is an abstract concept and I am getting confused since I barely understand the basics.

Comment: Just use a new controller which doesn't specify a `before_action` (an authentication filter), i.e. that will be publicly accessible. In that controller fetch whatever data you want to be publicly visible and pass them down to your views.